# command push_back results an exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) c++

Tags: c++, methods, memory-management, exit

I'm trying to make kind of a little game using c++, and I have to move a character from one point on the map to another one. When I try to do that by push_back and then erase from the source point I get this exit code. What am I doing wrong?
My code for moving is:

```
void Game::move(const GridPoint & src_coordinates, const GridPoint & dst_coordinates) {
    if(checkIfLegalCell(this, src_coordinates) == false ||
       checkIfLegalCell(this, dst_coordinates) == false) {
        throw IllegalCell();
    }
    if(searchInGrid(this->grid_characters, src_coordinates) == false){
        throw CellEmpty();
    }

    std::vector<Pair>::iterator it_src=this->grid_characters.begin();
    for(;it_src != this->grid_characters.end() ; ++it_src){
        if((*it_src).grid_point == src_coordinates){
            break;
        }
    }

    if( ((*it_src).character)->checkIfCanMove(src_coordinates, dst_coordinates) == false) {
        throw MoveTooFar();
    }

    if(searchInGrid(this->grid_characters, dst_coordinates) == true){
        throw CellOccupied();
    }

    this->grid_characters.push_back(Pair(dst_coordinates,(*it_src).character));
    this->grid_characters.erase(it_src);

}
```

And my main looks like that:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <cassert>

#include "Exceptions.h"
#include "Game.h"

using namespace mtm;

void example1() {
    std::cout << "------example 1------" << std::endl;
    Game g1(8,8);
    g1.addCharacter(GridPoint(1,1), Game::makeCharacter(CharacterType::MEDIC, Team::POWERLIFTERS, 10, 2, 4, 5));
    g1.addCharacter(GridPoint(1,4), Game::makeCharacter(CharacterType::SNIPER, Team::POWERLIFTERS, 10, 2, 4, 5));
    g1.addCharacter(GridPoint(6,1), Game::makeCharacter(CharacterType::SOLDIER, Team::CROSSFITTERS, 10, 2, 4, 5));
    g1.addCharacter(GridPoint(6,4), Game::makeCharacter(CharacterType::MEDIC, Team::CROSSFITTERS, 10, 2, 4, 5));
    std::cout << g1 << std::endl;
    g1.move(GridPoint(1,1), GridPoint(1,2));
    std::cout << g1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Nice!" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    example1();

    return 0;
}
```

It prints:

```
C:\Users\User\CLionProjects\gameMakerCurr.1\cmake-build-debug\ex0.exe
------example 1------
*****************
| | | | | | | | |
| |M| | |N| | | |
| | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | |
| |s| | |m| | | |
| | | | | | | | |
*****************

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

And this is the part of the "Game" that I'm using to create the pairs of- (coordinates, character)

```
struct Pair {
        GridPoint grid_point;
        std::shared_ptr<Character> character;
        Pair(GridPoint grid_point, std::shared_ptr<Character> character) :
                grid_point(grid_point), character(character) {}
    };

    class Game {
        std::vector<Pair> grid_characters; //  character by grid point ; key = grid_point ; value = character.
        int height;
        int width;
```

Any tips on how to fix this?

Comment: what if the loop exits without breaking and `it_src == this->grid_characters.end()` ?

Comment: The `push_back` can invalidate the iterator into the vector (if it needs to resize).

Comment: I cut this part of the code, but I'm checking before-hand that everything is fine, that there is a character and that the destination is in the map and is unoccupied

Comment: You cannot do `*it_src` if `it_src` is `end()`.

Comment: @Jeffrey it's not the end for sure, I'll update the move method so to not create this kind of confusion

Comment: programming pro-tip: if you know a condition will not happen, but would result in an error, put an assert, an error message, a early return or *anything*. Otherwise, fellow developers and nice stackoverflow contributors will point it out, resulting in time lost for you and them.

Comment: @Jeffrey I've updated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look attentively, in the program you trying to push the character to the end:

```cpp
    this->grid_characters.push_back(Pair(dst_coordinates,(*it_src).character));
    this->grid_characters.erase(it_src);
```

First of all, after you push a new element in the vector, it will likely reallocate data to have enough capacity to contain one more element. So after the push_back the vector moved the data to a new location in memory. After that are trying to erase using the it_src which still points to the location before the push_back.
So, before doing this, and before calculating the it_src, you must assure vector has enough capacity and will not relocate your data

```cpp
   if (this->grid_characters.capacity() <= this->grid_characters.size())
       this->grid_characters.reserve(this->grid_characters.size() + 10);
       //other variants
       //this->grid_characters.reserve(this->grid_characters.size() + 1);
       //this->grid_characters.reserve(this->grid_characters.size() * 2);
```

That should fix the failure.

But logically, why are you trying to move the object to the end? You change the coordinates from 1,1 to 1,2. In the vector it will be after the object with coordinates 6,4. Looks like the order in the vector is irelevant. If there is no much sense in the order of objects then it makes sense to change only coordinates, without moving it inside the vector

```cpp
    it_src->grid_point = dst_coordinates;
```

If the order matters use set.